# File permission in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, permissions

I have a VPS and use it for hosting my sites. The server is nginx with php-fdm.
my site is in the `/var/www/sitename/html/` and all the files and folders under the html directory owned by `www-data www-data`. All files permision is `664` and directories (html folder and sub-directories) has `775` permission. And also my user is member of the `www-data` group. 
I can change every files in this folder, but I can't make new file or new folder here. This need `sudo` privileges. I can create new file in the sub-directories like `/var/www/sitename/html/uploads` but not in the `/var/www/sitename/html/` while they have the same owner and permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user you are logging in as is not the www-data user or a member of the www-data group.

I set things up on my servers so that the user I log in as owns the files/directories, and a webuser group is the owning group, perms are set to 750/640.  You can automagically keep the owning group the same across all files/directories uploaded to/created on the server by making the top level web directory setgid.

```
drwxr-s---  4 debbie www-data  4096 Oct  6  2015 /var/www-debbie.example.com
```

If the webserver needs to write files, create the directory and change the permissions on it

```
sudo mkdir /var/www-debbie.example.com/writeable
sudo chmod 770 /var/www-debbie.example.com/writeable
```

If you haven't done the setgid thing, then fix the ownership

```
sudo chown debbie.www-data /var/www-debbie.example.com/writeable
```

And there ya go, the web server user can write to it.

```
drwxrws---  4 debbie www-data  4096 Oct  6  2015 /var/www-debbie.example.com/writeable
```